# Firestore: slow querying subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio

I noticed some performance issues in this python Cloud Function which queries FirestoreDB.

My DB structure is the following: a document `Match` contains two subcollections `l1` and `l2` (which have the same format). I want a function in the API to return a `Match` document along with both its subcollections

This is my code

```
 async def _get_match_firestore(match_id):
   db = AsyncClient()

   match_data = (await db.collection('matches').document(match_id).get()).to_dict()

   (match_data["l1"], match_data["l2"]) = await asyncio.gather(
      _read_subscriptions(match_id, "going"),
      _read_subscriptions(match_id, "refunded")
   )

   return match_data 


  async def _read_subscriptions(match_id, field_name):
      db = AsyncClient()
      res = {}

      collection = await db.collection('matches/{}/{}'.format(match_id, field_name)).get()

      for sub in collection:
          sub_dict = sub.to_dict()
      res[sub.id] = sub_dict

      return res
```

The async code that triggers in parallel the subcollections fetching is the slowest part of the function.

Am I doing something wrong here in the way I query subcollections and aggregate them to the final result? Or is there some clear misuse of the data model?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code above:

```
collection = await db.collection('matches/{}/{}'.format(match_id, field_name)).get()
```

You've oversight this query. You can't get the document field without accessing the sub-collection first.

Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.async_client.AsyncClient#google_cloud_firestore_v1_async_client_AsyncClient_collection), accessing sub-collection should be like this:

```
>>> client.collection('mydocs/doc/subcol')
>>> # is the same as
>>> client.collection('mydocs', 'doc', 'subcol')
```

hence, the query should be like:

```
collection = await db.collection('matches/{}/{}'.format(match_id, sub_col)).where('{}'.format(field_name), '==', True).get()
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Based on this lines of code:

```
   (match_data["l1"], match_data["l2"]) = await asyncio.gather(
      _read_subscriptions(match_id, "going"),
      _read_subscriptions(match_id, "refunded")
   )
```

As what I've understand, it means `match_data["l1"] = going` and `match_data["l2"] = refunded`.

I'm not sure what you're use-case is but I have written a working sample code on what I've understand on your question based on your given code and Firestore Data Structure above. Take a look at the snippet below:

```
# Added sub_collection names to pass on to _read_subscriptions
async def _get_match_firestore(match_id, sub_cols = ["l1", "l2"]):
    match_data = {}
    # Removed the 1st query here. You can re-add it if you are using it in you're use-case.
    (match_data["l1"], match_data["l2"]) = await asyncio.gather(
        _read_subscriptions(match_id, sub_cols[0], "going"),
        _read_subscriptions(match_id, sub_cols[1], "refunded")
    )

    return match_data

# Added `sub_col` to use on the query.
async def _read_subscriptions(match_id, sub_col, field_name):
    res = {}
    # This would get documents that are `going:True` on `l1` and `refunded:True` on `l2`
    collection = await db.collection('matches/{}/{}'.format(match_id, sub_col)).where('{}'.format(field_name), '==', True).get()

    for sub in collection:
        sub_dict = sub.to_dict()
    res[sub.id] = sub_dict

    return res
```

I left some comments on the code above. Feel free to improve or modify it for your use-case.